# How do I count unique multiple words in a Ruby string?

Tags: ruby, string, block

Trying to write a Ruby code that will count unique words and return their total occurrences.

So suppose I want to find number of occurrences for Sally, Marina and Tina in the following sentence "Monday Tina will meet Sally and Harris. Then Tina will visit her mom Marina. Marina and Tina will meet David for dinner."

I tried the following but this defeats the dry principal. Is there a better way?

```
string = "Monday Tina will meet Sally and Harris. Then Tina will visit her mom Marina. Marina and Tina will meet David for dinner. Sally will then take Tina out for a late night party." 

puts "Marina appears #{string.split.count("brown").to_i} times."
puts "Tina appears #{string.split.count("grey").to_i} times."
puts "Sally appears #{string.split.count("blue").to_i} times."
```

Expected result: program looks through the text for unique words and returns them.

Actual: I had to hard code each unique word on its own PUTS line and do string.split.count(for that unique word)

Note: 
I tried the following but this gives me EVERY word. I need to refine it to give me just the ones I ask for. This is where I am struggling.

```
def cw(string)
  w = string.split(' ')
  freq = Hash.new(0)
  w.each { |w| freq[w.downcase] += 1 }
  return freq
end
puts cw(string)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def count_em(str, who)
  str.gsub(/\b(?:#{who.join('|')})\b/i).
      each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |person,h| h[person] += 1 }
end

str = "Monday Tina will meet Sally and Harris. Then Tina will visit her " +
      "mom Marina. Marina and Tina will meet David for dinner. Sally will " +
      "then take Tina out for a late night party." 

who = %w| Sally Marina Tina |

count_em(str, who)
  #> {"Tina"=>4, "Sally"=>2, "Marina"=>2}
```

The first steps are as follows.

```
r = /\b(?:#{who.join('|')})\b/i
  #=> /\b(?:Sally|Marina|Tina)\b/i
enum = str.gsub(r)
  #=> #<Enumerator: "Monday Tina will meet Sally and Harris. Then
  #   ...
  #   for a late night party.":gsub(/\b(?:Sally|Marina|Tina)\b/i)>
```

We can convert this to an array to see the values that will be passed to `each_with_object`.

```
enum.to_a
  #=> ["Tina", "Sally", "Tina", "Marina", "Marina", "Tina", "Sally", "Tina"]
```

We then simply count the number of instances of the unique values generated by `enum`.

```
enum.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |person,h| h[person] += 1 }
  #=> {"Tina"=>4, "Sally"=>2, "Marina"=>2}
```

See [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-gsub), in particular the case when there is one argument and no block. This is admittedly an unusual use of `gsub`, as it is making no substitutions, but here I prefer it to `String#scan` because `gsub` returns an enumerator whereas scan produces a temporary array.

See also [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-c-new), the case where `new` takes an argument and no block. The argument is called the *default value*. If `h` is the hash so-defined, the default value is returned by `h[k]` if `h` does not have a key `k`. The hash is not altered.

Here the default value is zero. When the expression `h[person] += 1` it is parsed it is converted to:

```
h[person] = h[person] + 1
```

If `person` equals `"Tina"`, and it is the first time `"Tina"` is generated by the enumerator and passed to the block, `h` will not have a key `"Tina"`, so the expression becomes:

```
h["Tina"] = 0 + 1
```

as `0` is the default value. The next time `"Tina"` is passed to the block the hash has a key `"Tina"` (with value `1`), so the following calculation is performed.

```
h["Tina"] = h["Tina"] + 1 #=> 1 + 1 #=> 2
```

Comment: Eh. Would not `scan` be a bit more semantically correct than `gsub`? :)

Comment: This is neat. But it's a bit advanced; I haven't touched .gsub  yet. But thanks! I just need to figure out how to get a dummied down version.

Comment: mudsie, er @AlekseiMatiushkin, I prefer `gsub` over `scan` because the former produces an enumerator whereas the latter constructs an intermediate array. Besides, it's important to educate people of the usefulness of `gsub` when used with one argument and no block.,

Comment: You win the game always! :(

Comment: @Rajagopalan, the game? Not a fight to the death?

Comment: Just kidding !I meant  You always come with the best solution

Comment: @Rajagopalan, no, no, no. Many of our colleagues frequently post solutions that I wish I had thought of.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, I just proposed that a method [String#matches](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/15446) be added to the Ruby core. It would be an alias of the form of `gsub` that returns an enumerator.

Comment: The use of `gsub` is confusing – no substitution is being performed here (I doubt that this form is useful at all in the context of substitution). I'd simply use `scan` with a block, e.g. `h = Hash.new(0) ; str.scan(...) { |m| h[m] += 1 } ; h`. Or maybe `Hash.new(0).tap { ... }` if you want to avoid the explicit return value.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - I appreciate the clarity in your annotated comment. This helped me on several cases.  Turns out .gsub is a powerful tool.

Answer (score 0):

To get only the required people name:

```
people = ['Marina', 'Tina', 'Sally', 'Dory']
tmp = string.scan(/\w+/).keep_if{ |w| people.include? w }
counts people.map{ |name| [name, tmp.count{|n| n == name }] }.to_h
counts #=> {"Marina"=>2, "Tina"=>4, "Sally"=>2, "Dory"=>0}
```

This maps the `peopole` array against `tmp` to a nested array containing `[name, count]`, then converted to a hash.

The good is that it returns `0` if people doesn't appear, see `'Dory'`.

---

To get the total count, two ways:

```
tmp.size #=> 8
counts.values.sum #=> 8
```

Comment: I was able to achieve this but then had to manually return or print each of the key words (in this case I am only looking for how many times three unique words are occurring). I have been able to get my function to show me ALL occurrences; I want it to show only the three words I am looking for.

Comment: You are abusing `each` iteration to perform reducing. `string.scan(/\w+/).map(&:downcase).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|w, h| h[w] += 1 }`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, yes, I just wanted to split the steps, just to keep it easier to follow. Of course `each_with_object` is really handy.

Comment: @iGian, how would I tally them up to a total? So final line would show 8 occurrences of names.