# How can I find a category of words in a string and take their tally in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

Given a sentence, I want to tally up the total number of times a category of noun (people vs. animals) is present. This is not the same as finding out how many number of times each of the words occur. Nor am I looking for the total number of times each designated word occurs but rather the tally of total occurrences of all designated words in an array. While advanced methods are appreciated, the search is on for simpler more beginner level coding; one liner coding may be great and sincerely appreciated but I want to have an understanding as a beginner.

In the sentence "John and Mary like horses, ducks, and dogs." I want to tally up the number of animals (3).

```
str = "John and Mary like horses, ducks, and dogs."

animals= ["horses", "ducks", "dogs"]

def count_a(string)
  animals = 0
  i = 0
  while i < string.length  
    if (string[i]=="horses" || string[i]=="ducks" || 
      string[i]=="dogs")
      animals +=1
    end

    i +=1
  end
end
puts count_a(str)
```

Expecting: 3
Actual: not showing anything in return

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I count unique multiple words in a Ruby string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53879938/how-do-i-count-unique-multiple-words-in-a-ruby-string)

Answer (score 2):

```
> str.scan(Regexp.union(animals)).size
# => 3
```

Change Regexp to

```
Regexp.new(animals.join("|"), true)
```

for case insensitive match.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin thanks, edited :). Not sure if it's possible to make union be case insensitive in any sane manner.

Comment: I can think of `Regexp.new(Regexp.union(...), [1])` or `/#{Regexp.union(...)}/i`, but neither looks sane enough to me. Also, hijacking `Regexp.union(...).options` does not seem possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works one letter at a time:

```
"abcd"[0]
=> "a"
```

Then your condition compares that letter to a word:

```
"abcd"[0] == "duck"
# which is the same as:
"a" == "duck"
# which will never be true
```

You can split the string into an array of words and use `Array#count` and `Array#include?` to count occurences:

```
ANIMALS = ["horses", "ducks", "dogs"]

def count_a(string)
  string.split(/\b/).count { |word| ANIMALS.include?(word) }
end

puts count_a("John and Mary like horses, ducks, and dogs.")
```

To search matches inside words, like "bulldog" counting as a dog, you can use:

```
def count_a(string)
  ANIMALS.inject(0) { |count, animal| count + string.scan(animal).size }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your logic, fix like this (see inline comments):

```
def count_a(string)
  string = string.scan(/\w+/).map(&:downcase) # <------------ split into words
  animals = 0
  i = 0
  while i < string.length
    if (string[i]=="horses" || string[i]=="ducks" || 
      string[i]=="dogs")
      animals +=1
    end
    i +=1
  end
  return animals # <------------ return the count
end

puts count_a(str) #=> 3
```